# Cabal error running with Gloss

Tags: haskell, cabal, gloss

I'm  trying to install gloss on my computer to make a graphic game and I followed a tutorial, with these steps:

1) First I run this command: cabal install gloss==1.8.* . I want gloss 1.8.* because I found a game made with this version of gloss, and I understand that it is recommended to use the same version of gloss with which the game was made it.
I have this on the cmd: 
[image: installing gloss]

2)Next, once gloss is installed, we have to tell cabal that our package is allowed to use it. I founnd the line in pong.cabal that mentions build-depends and change it to the following:

build-depends:       base >=4.7 && <4.8, gloss==1.8.*

3) Finally, I wanted to run my .hs file(which contain the code to make a "nice window" with a circle) with the command: cabal run; the result of this command:

[image: running .hs file]

I don't understand why cabal can't find the gloss 1.8*.
Anyone can help me with this problem?

Comment: Your step 1 failed so naturally step 3 will fail as well.  Gloss 1.8.* was depends on an OLDER version of base than your version of GHC shipped with.

Comment: i understand, but how can I find with which version of ghc, gloss 1.8.* works?

Comment: The only way is sort of round-about.  You look at the gloss 1.8.* 'base' dependency and see what that version is.  The base version maps to a GHC version, so you can translate between the two.  For example, I use GHC 7.10.3 which ships with base 4.8.2.0.

Comment: The path I'd pick would be to try the library with gloss-1.10*.  It might not require any changes beyond adjusting the version bound in the .cabal file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gloss 1.8.2.2 requires base 4.7.* (see the cabal file). The [release notes](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/release-7-8-1.html#idp5507360) for GHC 7.8.3 state that it comes with base 4.7.0.0.

Comment: It is a way now to install base 4.7 with cabal? Even if I have a newer version of ghc..or I have to uninstall haskell and look for an older version?

Comment: Not really. Significant parts of base are tied to the version of GHC. But have you just tried compiling with an up-to-date verison of Gloss? Its going to be easier.

Answer (score 0):

The package gloss 1.8.* depends on base 4.6 or base 4.7. Cabal sandbox is a good choice for you. You can initialize a sandbox, then install base 4.7 and gloss 1.8 in it.